# How do i get my DIVS to change content just like the buttons, without adding an onclick function on the html

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am working with a WordPress theme which has no input for onclick on the divs. But i can assign classes and IDs only.

I have four spans in a row, and onclick of each column, I want the corresponding paragraph to show.

I was able to do for buttons that have onclick properties, but unable to do for the columns.

Please help review the code and see how I can a JS to call the paragraphs to change by calling an ID, without having to put on click on the HTML. The on-click can be in the JavaScript or CSS.

```js
function changeElement(num) {
  document.getElementById(`paragraph_${num}`).style.display = 'block';
  const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4].filter((elem) => elem !== num);
  arr.forEach((elem) => {
    document.getElementById(`paragraph_${elem}`).style.display = 'none';
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 20px;
  justify-items: center;
}

span {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
// the divs that correspond to each button below
<div>
  <span>Div 1</span>
  <span>Div 2</span>
  <span>Div 3</span>
  <span>Div 4</span>
</div>
   
<p id="paragraph_1">paragraph 1</p>
<p id="paragraph_2" class="none">paragraph 2</p>
<p id="paragraph_3" class="none">paragraph 3</p>
<p id="paragraph_4" class="none">paragraph 4</p>
</body>
```

Comment: can you please explain your desired output better so I can help you

Comment: I want each paragraph to show if a corresponding div is clicked. without adding onclick on the html

Comment: So just add onclick function on the span tag also same as you added on the button tags

Comment: @Hems i cannot add onclick on the wordpress builder. I need to call the onclick directly from the javascript

Comment: If you can add id on the main div so you can easily target it for the javascript function. Here is your code https://jsfiddle.net/6vzj9soc/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since oyu cant add an 'onlcik' on the html, I was thinking you could call the javascript by injecting it with JavaScript with the `setAttribute()` method.

**Here is the code:**

```js
  function set_event(){
    const Div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    const Div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
    const Div3 = document.getElementById('div3');
    const Div4 = document.getElementById('div4');
    Div1.setAttribute("onclick", "changeElement(1)");
    Div2.setAttribute("onclick", 'changeElement(2)');
    Div3.setAttribute("onclick", 'changeElement(3)');
    Div4.setAttribute("onclick", 'changeElement(4)');
  }
  window.onload = set_event();

  function changeElement(num) {
    document.getElementById(`paragraph_${num}`).style.display = 'block';
    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4].filter((elem) => elem !== num);
    arr.forEach((elem) => {
      document.getElementById(`paragraph_${elem}`).style.display = 'none';
    })
  }
```

```css
    body {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .none {
      display: none;
    }

    div {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      gap: 20px;
      justify-items: center;
    }

    span {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
// the divs that correspond to each button below
<div>
  <span id='div1'>Div 1</span>
  <span id='div2'>Div 2</span>
  <span id='div3'>Div 3</span>
  <span id='div4'>Div 4</span>
</div>
   
<p id="paragraph_1">paragraph 1</p>
<p id="paragraph_2" class="none">paragraph 2</p>
<p id="paragraph_3" class="none">paragraph 3</p>
<p id="paragraph_4" class="none">paragraph 4</p>

<script>

</script>
```

Comment: @amarachi always a pleasure to help someone